# Is it possible in pagePiling.js to add a stop once the bottom of a section has been reached?

Tags: javascript, html, pagepiling.js

Is it possible in pagePiling.js to add a stop once the bottom of a section has been reached?

Thanks in advance.

Sachin

Comment: The website that I am working on is
ahau.io
When I am reaching at the last page, I don't want it to move to page 1.

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X?" / "Can I do X?" / "Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you want. Right now, this is a "yes"/"no" question. Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273)

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

Just make use of the method `setAllowScrolling(false)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pagepiling').pagepiling();
    $.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(false);
});
```